# Hide Tab Bar from mouse in FireFox fullscreen mode

Tags: firefox, mouse, fullscreen, firefox-quantum

When I go fullscreen in firefox, and move the mouse to the top of the screen to click something up there, my mouse accidentally hits the top of the screen and makes firefox show the tab bar, which jolts the page down. Its very annoying.

I want to never see the tab bar when in fullscreen mode, completely hidden and therefore the mouse can hit the top of the screen without making any changes.

How can this be accomplished? I'm on Firefox Quantum 57

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your userChrome.css:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#nav-bar[inFullscreen="true"] { display:none!important; }
#TabsToolbar[inFullscreen="true"] { display:none!important; }
```

Comment: There's still a single pixel line that pops up. Any idea how to fix that? (Or how to inspect things to fix it?)